# How do I display taxonomy child terms?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I used the *Taxonomy View Depth* module to create a taxonomy vocabulary like this.

#### Animal

- Cats

  - Brown
  - white
- Dogs

  - Brown
  - White

What I did was enabling the default taxonomy view, and changing the depth in *Content: Has taxonomy term ID* (with depth) to 1 instead of 0 (also tried 2,3, etc.)

The children items will never show on the page. It does remove the **There is currently no content classified with this term.** from the page.

**What I want?** With Taxonomy menu I want to be able to click Cats and show the second level children.

Answer (score 1):

I used [View tree](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_tree) Module to achieve this same kind of functionality but i used it for Node Reference. As per their module page, this module is also compatible for taxonomy.

**Here are the steps to set Views Tree to display hierarchical taxonomy.**

Create a new term view using the fields row style

1. add relationship for taxonomy term: parent term
2. add field term id (do not use relationship) and exclude it from display
3. add field term id with relationship, exclude from display
4. add any fields you want to display, like term name, term description, etc...
5. Change style plugin to Tree (Adjacency model)
6. Set Main field to Term ID
7. Set Parent field to Term ID with parent relationship

Comment: Will try this when i get home from work. Will let you know. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If using Drupal 7, views I has changed a lot from the year the question was asked.

In the view,

**Filter criteria:**
Add

`Content: Has taxonomy terms (with depth) (exposed)` **exposed** is used when you are using `BEF settings` and want the **visitor** be able to modify the exposed filter.

Select the taxonomy **vocabulary:** like `Animal` from question.

Important step **Selection type:** `Dropdown` if autocomplete is selected show hierarchy wont show as a option.
Drop down gives a option to choose the checkbox for `show hierarchy`

**Depth:** This option depends on the maximum child items you want to choose for a term as asked in question `cats` and `dogs` has child terms with depth `1`, means if you want to see the content tagged to `brown` when you select `cats` term `depth: 1` is prefered. If the child terms also have child terms then we need to increase the depth. For example if

`Animals
-cats
--brown
---lightbrown
--black`

As Child term `brown` has `lightbrown` as child term, and if you prefer to show the content tagged to `lightbrown` if `cats` were selected then `depth: 2` is recommended.