# Taxonomy Term Hierarchy(not programmatically nor content related)

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I know there are zillion topics about this, but I just couldn't apply it to my View Block in Drupal 8. On the other hand all these Taxonomy Term Tree creation is based on content related.

Here is what I would like to do, I would like to display my "Collections" taxonomy term hierarchy without content relationship, as it is(just parent-child terms). This is how my taxonomy term hierarchy looks like:

[image]

And this is how far I could get:

[image]

This is my result(which is completely wrong):

[image]

**FYI: I am using Views Tree and I follow this [Taxonomy display children with Taxonomy View Depth not working](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/147565/taxonomy-display-children-with-taxonomy-view-depth-not-working) **

Thank you for help and time in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the *Views Tree* module for this: https://www.drupal.org/project/views_tree

It works pretty well, you just need to use the Tree (list) views **FORMAT**, add the parent taxonomy term in **RELATIONSHIPS**, add the parent term's *Name* field to the **FIELDS** list, and then use it as the *Parent field* on the Tree settings:

[image: Tree (list) settings]

The module will link the terms hierarchically and output a nested list, and you can always hide the parent term's name field to show just the children terms names.